# Creating database driven System.Timers.Timer for Windows Service

Tags: .net, windows-services, timer

I'm trying to create System.Timers.Timer dynamically based on paramters in the database. For example, if the table has 5 rows. I need to created 5 timers. There paramters like start time & intervals are stored in the database. How can you do this?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your database records in an object collection or an array??  You could loop through and add the timers to a dictionary using the primary key as the key.

EG:

```
Dictionary<string,Timer> timers = new Dictionary<string,Timer>();
```

Then for each of your records:

```
timers.Add(PrimaryKeyOfRecord, new Timer());
```

then you can access like this:

```
timers[PrimaryKeyOfRecord].Start();
```

Comment: thanks Oliver. what about adding a block of code for each timer as they tick?